# pytesseract not recognizing numbers in picture using OCR

Tags: python-3.x, python-tesseract

I'm trying to use Python-tesseract to extract the digits from this ([picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7FU1W.png)) using  optical character recognition (OCR). For some reason pytesseract won't recognize the digits and I don't fully understand why (distance between the numbers?).

Can someone assist me in understanding how to properly extract the digits from this image?

The code below doesn't print anything

```
     im.save("sudo.png")
     text = pytesseract.image_to_string(im)
     print(text)
```

Answer (score 0):

A little bit of pre-processing and using ROIs to specify where the words are will help. By default, OCR uses page layout analysis to determine blocks of text. In this case, the image doesn't look like a normal page of text (like a PDF article for example).
To make it easier for OCR, first you can find the location of the words using regionprops and then pass the location of the words (as bounding boxes) to the OCR function. See the code below and results. They look accurate. You may have to play around more with the pre-processing to make this robust for a collection of different images. But hopefully, this gives you an idea on how to proceed:

```
    capture = imread('Captura.PNG');
    % Increase image size by 3x
    my_image = imresize(capture, 3);
    figure
    imshow(my_image)
    % Localize words
    BW = imbinarize(rgb2gray(my_image));
    BW1 = imdilate(BW,strel('disk',6));
    s = regionprops(BW1,'BoundingBox');
    bboxes = vertcat(s(:).BoundingBox);
    % Sort boxes by image height
    [~,ord] = sort(bboxes(:,2));
    bboxes = bboxes(ord,:);
    % Pre-process image to make letters thicker
    BW = imdilate(BW,strel('disk',1));
    % Call OCR and pass in location of words. Also, set TextLayout to 'word'
    ocrResults = ocr(BW,bboxes,'CharacterSet','.0123456789','TextLayout','word');
    words = {ocrResults(:).Text}';
    words = deblank(words)
```